# LibSRTP using another AES mode

Tags: c, aes

libsrtp is using AES GCM for encrypt media, and i'm trying to use another AES to encrypt my media like AES OFB.
here is the libsrtp repo: https://github.com/cisco/libsrtp

```
static srtp_err_status_t srtp_aes_gcm_openssl_encrypt (void *cv, unsigned char *buf, unsigned int *enc_len)
{
    srtp_aes_gcm_ctx_t *c = (srtp_aes_gcm_ctx_t *)cv;
    if (c->dir != srtp_direction_encrypt && c->dir != srtp_direction_decrypt) {
        return (srtp_err_status_bad_param);
    }

    /*
     * Encrypt the data
     */
    EVP_Cipher(c->ctx, buf, buf, *enc_len);

    return (srtp_err_status_ok)
}
```

Should i change the existing AES GCM to AES OFB? Where should i start changing then?
Any suggestion?